# PHP sorting array based on start and end value

Tags: php, arrays, loops, sorting

I have an array with different events in it. Every event has a starting hour and ending hour. I want to sort the array based on these values.

```
Array
(
    [41] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [event] => event1
                    [start] => 0930
                    [end] => 1200
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [event] => event1
                    [start] => 1000
                    [end] => 1230
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [event] => event1
                    [start] => 1100
                    [end] => 1300
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [event] => event1
                    [start] => 1400
                    [end] => 1630
                )

        )

    [52] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [event] => event2
                    [start] => 0930
                    [end] => 1030
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [event] => event2
                    [start] => 0930
                    [end] => 1030
                )

        )
)
```

This is what my loop looks like and what I've tried to sorting it:

```
foreach($attractieIDs as $id) {
        foreach($slots[$id] as $attractions){

            $sortedSlots = usort($slots[$id], function($a, $b){
                return $a['start'] - $b['start'];
            });

        }
    }
```

To be completely honest with you guys I actually have no idea what I am doing :D

I don't really understand how the usort works, even though I've read through the php manual several times

Anyone who could help me out please

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You wanna sort the array based on `start` hour right ?

Comment: use array_multisort()

Comment: @Aurel Yes, eventualy I need to build a system to check if there are events that overlap but let's start with sorting them :)

Comment: @Frank Lucas Which variable corresponds to your array in your code ?

Comment: @Aurel attractieIDs is an array with the event id's in them (41,52) and $slots is the array I showed in OP. So I loop over $slots per attractieID and then $attractions is basically 1 event, do you understand?

Comment: I edited my answer based on what I understood, does it work for you ?

Comment: Check edited code with your desire output. @FrankLucas

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use `usort()`. `$myArray` is your current array.

```
    $myArray= Array( 41=>array( 
        0=>array(
            "event" => "event1",
            "start" => 930,
            "end" => 1200
        ),
        1=>array(
            "event" => "event3",
            "start" => 1100,
            "end" => 1300
        ),
        2=>array(
            "event" => "event2",
            "start" => 1000,
            "end" => 1230
        )
    ),
    52=> array(
        0=>array(
            "event" => "event1",
            "start" => 930,
            "end" => 1030
        ),
        1=>array(
            "event" => "event3",
            "start" => 1100,
            "end" => 1300
        ),
    )
);
```

**Code**

```
function sortByStartTime($a, $b) {
    return $a['start'] - $b['start'];
}

foreach($myArray as $key=>$array)
{
    usort($array, 'sortByStartTime');
    echo "<pre>";
    $newArray[$key] = $array;

}
print_r($newArray);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [41] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [event] => event1
                    [start] => 930
                    [end] => 1200
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [event] => event2
                    [start] => 1000
                    [end] => 1230
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [event] => event3
                    [start] => 1100
                    [end] => 1300
                )

        )

    [52] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [event] => event1
                    [start] => 930
                    [end] => 1030
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [event] => event3
                    [start] => 1100
                    [end] => 1300
                )

        )

)
```

**Check Live Demo : [Click Here](https://eval.in/556829)**

Comment: What do I use to access my sorted array?

Comment: just print $myArray after sort function.

Comment: I just get 1 printed out after every $attractions

Comment: check live demo. @FrankLucas

Comment: Problem is you're forgetting that it's a multidimensional array you need to pass $attractieID(41,52) somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You can use usort like that :

```
foreach($attractieIDs as $id) {
    usort($slots[$id], function($a, $b) {
       return $a['start'] - $b['start'];
    });
}
```

I'm using the following `$attractieIDs` and `$slots` arrays and it works nicely :

```
$attractieIDs = [41, 52];

$slots = [
    41 => [
        [
            "event" => "event1",
            "start" => 930,
            "end" => 1200
        ],
        [
            "event" => "event3",
            "start" => 1100,
            "end" => 1300
        ],
        [
            "event" => "event2",
            "start" => 1000,
            "end" => 1230
        ]
    ],
    52 => [
        [
            "event" => "event3",
            "start" => 1100,
            "end" => 1300
        ],
        [
            "event" => "event2",
            "start" => 1000,
            "end" => 1230
        ],
        [
            "event" => "event1",
            "start" => 930,
            "end" => 1200
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: attractieIDs is an array with only the ids in them(41 and  52) and slots is my array that I posted in OP

Comment: Okay seems to work but when I try to loop out every event like this: `foreach($slots[$id] as $attractions)` It seems to only loop out the events of the first id

Comment: Are you sure it isn't because the content of the two IDs in my example is exactly the same ?